# ntfs external HD works read-only on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, ntfs

I only have read-only access to my external hard-drive which is using NTFS filesystem. How do I fix this problem to get full access to my hard drive?

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the [ntfs-3g filesystem driver](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/ntfs-3g/) and mount your drive using that instead of your current ntfs driver.